# Butterknife is not binding the objects after migration to andoidX

Tags: butterknife

I have recently updated to androidX . Now I have updated the butterknife library, But when I build the project butterknife is not able to bind view and crashing every time.

Plugins

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
//apply plugin: 'com.android.library' //because we are not creating library
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
```

```html
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
//    maven {
//        url "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"
//    }

}
```

```html
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
```

This is my app.gradle file

Comment: Please provide the information you get from the crash

Comment: I have solved the issue. How?
1. I redo the android X migration from the Android studio tool.
2. integrate the new plugins required for butterknife
3. Solve all the errors